# Prove $a+a=1$ using field table

Tags: finite-fields

Suppose a field $F=\{0,1,a\}$, what would be the table for addition . I know that for addition table, to prove  $a+a=1$

Comment: You should be able to fill in more of the multiplication table, e.g. the second row and second column.

Comment: A finite field is not an **ordered** field.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finite Fields of Order 3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/233854/finite-fields-of-order-3)

Comment: @hardmath 1*1 =1 1*x =x, x*1 =x x*x=1(because u cant have multiple values?)

Comment: Okay, you seem to have switched from $a$ to $x$ for the nonzero, non-identity element.  But that fills out the multiplication table.  How about addition?

Comment: first row is 0 1 a and second row is 0 1 and x, idk about the rest

Comment: Both the addition and multiplication tables are "symmetric" about their diagonals (because addition and multiplication are both commutative operations in a field).

Comment: wow thanks for that info lol, how would i prove x+x=1

Comment: @Bob What exactly do you mean by $x$? Your field only has the elements $0,1$, and $a$.

Comment: sorry im used to using x, its a though

Comment: You shouldn't need multiplication; the fact that $(F,+)$ is a group is enough. Note that since $a,1\neq0$, $a+1$ can't equal $1$ or $a$, so $a+1=0$. Since $a\neq1$, $a+a$ can't equal $0$ or $a$, so $a+a=1$.

Comment: @stewbasic if u dont mind can u explain a bit, i dont get a,1=!0 and why a!=1 and a+a!=0

Answer (score 1):

$(F,+)$ is an Abelian group and there is only one group with three elements. Specifically, if $x \in F$ and $x \ne 0$ then the subgroup generated by $x$ must have an order dividing $3$ by Lagrange's theorem. Therefore $(F,+)$ is a cyclic group of order $3$.

Answer (score 0):

As you stated the first row and first column of the multiplication table are zero entries. The row/column belonging to $1 \in F$ are the identity row/column. This leaves $a*a=1$ as $F$ is a field and $a$ must have an inverse which certainly is not $1$ nor $0$. Now, as $F$ has three elements and is a group under addition, $(F,+) \cong  C_3$ the cyclic group of order 3. By looking at the table of $C_3$ we deduce that $1+1 \neq a+a$. Further, we have $a +a \neq 0$ else we would have
\begin{equation}a+a = 0 \implies a(a+a) = a(0) \implies 1+1=0
\end{equation}
which contradicts our aforementioned deduction. Finally, as $C_3$ can have no idempotent elements other than the identity, this leaves us with $a +a =1$.

Answer (score 0):

What is $a+1$?

If $a+1=a $ then $a+1-a=a-a $ and $1=0$.  That's impossible.

If $a+1=1$ then $a+1-1=1-1$ and $a=0$. That's impossible.

So $a+1=0$.

So what is $a+a $?

If $a+a=0$ then $a=a+0=a+a+1=0+1=1$.  That is impossible.

If $a+a=a $ then $a+a+1=a+1$ so $a+0=a=0$.  That is impossible.

The only option left is $a+a=1$.

Comment: why are u doing a+1?

Comment: To figure out what a+a is, is simply a matter of figuring out what a+1 *isn't*. If a+a = 0 then a+1 = 1 which is impossible.